# Convert same time to different time zone

Tags: c#, timezone, nodatime

I am trying to convert times to different time zones, but not the way you're thinking. I need to convert a DateTime that is 9am EST to 9am CST on the UTC for example. The timezones are variable so just adding/subtracting hours doesn't seem correct way to do it with NodaTime

```
Fri, 21 Feb 2014 21:00:00 EST = 1393034400 Epoch Timestamp
convert to
Fri, 21 Feb 2014 21:00:00 CST = 1393030800 Epoch Timestamp
```

Comment: Please post any code you have to perform this, at this point.

Comment: You mean like 9pm EST to 8pm Central Time?

Comment: For example, I need to convert 9pm EST (or whatever zone) to 9pm Central (or whatever zone) according to the UTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you're trying to convert a date/time in one time zone to another one that has the same local time and a different time zone; that is, a different point in time.

You can do this with Noda Time by combining the `LocalDateTime` with the new zone.  For example, given something like the following:

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
DateTimeZone eastern = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
ZonedDateTime nowEastern = now.InZone(eastern);
```

`nowEastern` is the time now in the `America/New_York` time zone.  If we print `nowEastern` directly to the console, we'll see something like `2014-02-22T05:18:50 America/New_York (-05)`.

As an aside, "EST" and "CST" aren't time zones: they're non-unique abbreviations for a particular offset within a time zone; `America/New_York` and `America/Chicago` are probably representative of what we think of as "Eastern" and "Central", though (or you could use something like `UTC-05:00` if you really wanted EST even when daylight savings time was in effect).

Given a `ZonedDateTime` in any time zone, we can convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` with the same local time and a specified time zone as follows:

```
DateTimeZone central = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
ZonedDateTime sameLocalTimeCentral = nowEastern.LocalDateTime.InZoneStrictly(central);
```

This gives us a `ZonedDateTime` with the same local time, but a different time zone.  With the input above, the result would be `2014-02-22T05:18:50 America/Chicago (-06)`.

Note that I'm using `InZoneStrictly`. This will [throw an exception](http://nodatime.org/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZoneStrictly.htm) if the local time is ambiguous or invalid (for example, during daylight savings transitions).  If that's unacceptable, you could use `InZoneLeniently`, which picks the earliest valid `ZonedDateTime` on or after the given local time, or `InZone`, which allows you to specify your own rules in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

On Msdn [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find all you need.

Small example:

```
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} UTC.", 
               TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateNow));
```

Go to the link for more details on what you want, I can't give you more with that small description